# Retrieve last updated record in SQL with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table, which has around 2 million records and out of these there are around 70000 records which have duplicate Deal ID's.
1. Here for only duplicated Deal ID records I want to consider the record with last updated Month(**FP**).
2. only if the Last Updated Month(**FP**) is Equal then the record with **Source** = **'MDM'** needs to selected.
3. Deal ID can be repeated many times.
4. Important is we need to consider only Deal ID which has repetitions.

[image: Sample Data]
I have tried by grouping Deal ID's and having the records count greater than **1** and by doing inner join with the records having count > 1 stored in other table , and with Rank, but here I am not able to retrieve the records required.

Output should be something like this

[image]
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/46b96/2) for sample data

Comment: You can use MAX(FP) Group BY Deal and Add condition where Source = 'MDM'

Comment: Apologies, I have edited Question and now it is more precise, I need all the columns in table, if group by all the columns then there will be no duplicates.

Comment: Images are nice to convey a concept. However, for queries it's poor form to show the data without actually showing it. A table definition and the values as text are preferable

Comment: How did you eliminate Deal 2662345 FP 200904 from the above? Since the FPs didn't match for that set, I'd have expected them to be preserved

Comment: @billinkc, for the same Deal ID, if the FP is different, then we need to consider the recent/largest FP, it was mentioned in Point1, only if FP is same for same Deal ID then we need to go for Point 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like basic ROW_NUMBER case, doesn't it?

```
select * 
from (
  select *,
    [rank] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
      partition by deal
      order by fp desc, case when source = 'MDM' then 0 else 1 end asc
    )
  from src
) ranked
where [rank] = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/46b96/12

Comment: Leonid you rock, Thank you very much, It made my work very simple. I am learning lot here.

Answer (score 0):

give this a try

```
Select * from [table] 
where DealId in(
Select DealId from [table]
Group by DealId 
Having count(DealId) > 1)
where source = 'MDM'
```

this should give you all the records with duplicate dealIds and source = 'mdm'

Comment: Requirement is bit different

Answer (score 0):

Select a row if no newer with same deal exists:

```
select * from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t1.deal = t2.deal
                    and t2.fp > t1.fp)
```

Comment: Still I am seeing duplicates, I have edited my Question